# How to use DumpMem to display Stack in Assembly

Tags: assembly, x86, masm, irvine32

Okay so here is my problem. After I push a variable onto the stack and then create room for the local variable. **How do I use DumpMem to display the stack before I return from the procedure?**

```
include irvine32.inc

.data
X   sdword   10, -10, 20, -20, 30, -30, 40, -40

.code
begin:
mov ecx, offset x
push ecx
call StackProcedure

StackProcedure PROC
        push ebp
        mov ebp, esp
        sub esp, 32
        lea esi, [ebp-32]
        mov ecx, 32
L1:     mov BYTE PTR [esi], '*'
        inc esi
        loop L1
        add esp, 32
        pop ebp
        ret
StackProcedure ENDP

finfin:
invoke exitProcess,0
end begin
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Irvine's [`DumpMem`](http://programming.msjc.edu/asm/help/index.html?page=source%2Firvinelib%2Fdumpmem.htm) needs just three values in registers. Only these registers are attached, everything else (registers, memory, stack) is unchanged when the function returns. So, its use is easy:

```
include irvine32.inc

.data
    X sdword   10, -10, 20, -20, 30, -30, 40, -40

.code

StackProcedure PROC
    push ebp
    mov ebp, esp
    sub esp, 32
    lea esi, [ebp-32]
    mov ecx, 32
L1: mov BYTE PTR [esi], '*'
    inc esi
    loop L1

        mov esi, esp                ; Start address
        mov ecx, 48                 ; Number of bytes to dump
        mov ebx, 1                  ; 1 - size byte
        call DumpMem                ; call Irvine's DumpMem

    add esp, 32
    pop ebp
    ret
StackProcedure ENDP

main PROC
    mov ecx, offset x
    push ecx
    call StackProcedure
    invoke exitProcess,0
main ENDP

END main
```

I guess this was not actually asked about. Irvine's [`DumpMem`](http://programming.msjc.edu/asm/help/index.html?page=source%2Firvinelib%2Fdumpmem.htm) shows no addresses except the start address and no equivalent ASCII characters as expected in a disassembler dump. Since it has its own display (title and line feeds) it cannot be embedded between functions that provide that additional information. Here is a function that displays a row of 16 bytes with address, hex values and ASCII characters:

```
include irvine32.inc

.data
    X sdword   10, -10, 20, -20, 30, -30, 40, -40

.code

DumpMemLine PROC C USES EBX ESI, address:PTR      ; dumps 16 bytes hex & char
    mov eax, address
    call WriteHex               ; call Irvine's WriteHex (8 hex digits)
    mov al, ' '
    call WriteChar              ; call Irvine's WriteChar (space)
    call WriteChar              ; call Irvine's WriteChar (space)

    mov esi, address
    mov ecx, 16
    L1:
    mov al, [esi]
    cmp al, 14                  ; ASCII code >= 14d?
    jae @F                      ; Yes, can be written unchanged
    cmp al, 7                   ; ASCII code < 7d?
    jb @F                       ; Yes, can be written unchanged
    cmp al, 11                  ; ASCII code == 11d?
    je @F                       ; Yes, can be written unchanged
    cmp al, 12                  ; ASCII code == 12d?
    je @F                       ; Yes, can be written unchanged
    mov al, ' '                 ; Replace characters that `WriteChar` will "cook" (7,8,9,10,13)
    @@:                         ; This is label where the `jcond @F` jump to
    mov ebx, 1                  ; Two hex digits
    call WriteHexB              ; call Irvine's WriteHexB
    mov al, ' '
    call WriteChar              ; call Irvine's WriteChar (space)
    inc esi
    loop L1
    call WriteChar              ; call Irvine's WriteChar (space)

    mov esi, address
    mov ecx, 16
    @@:
    mov al, [esi]
    call WriteChar              ; call Irvine's WriteChar
    inc esi
    loop @B

    mov al, 10
    call WriteChar              ; call Irvine's WriteChar (line feed)

    ret
DumpMemLine ENDP

StackProcedure PROC
    push ebp
    mov ebp, esp
    sub esp, 32
    lea esi, [ebp-32]
    mov ecx, 32
L1: mov BYTE PTR [esi], '*'
    inc esi
    loop L1

        mov esi, esp                ; Start address
        mov ecx, 48                 ; Number of bytes to dump
        mov ebx, 1                  ; 1 - size byte
        call DumpMem                ; call Irvine's DumpMem

        ; Dump three lines à 16 bytes
        push esp                    ; Argument for DumpMemLine
        call DumpMemLine
        add dword ptr [esp], 16     ; Increment the pushed argument
        call DumpMemLine
        add dword ptr [esp], 16     ; Increment the pushed argument
        call DumpMemLine
        add esp, 4                  ; Clean up the stack

    add esp, 32
    pop ebp
    ret
StackProcedure ENDP

main PROC
    mov ecx, offset x
    push ecx
    call StackProcedure
    invoke exitProcess,0
main ENDP

END main
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying to see the memory dump, if its currect, You can use GDB debugger to debug your program and also you can see the memory details like registers, segments, control registers, frames etc... by setting break points,  and follow the link to get more on GDB,

```
http://www.yolinux.com/TUTORIALS/GDB-Commands.html
```